# Exec powershell.exe hangs msbuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, msbuild, freeze

I'm currently looking into re-jigging our hacked together deployment system with something a little more elegant - Octopus.  In doing so, I'm trying to get VS to package up a project when a release build is run.  Well I have this fancy powershell script written and working, but when I try to EXEC from the msbuild script, visual studio just hangs!

At first I suspected the way stuff was being escaped in the shell, but I simplified it ridiculously, and it still freezes.

Here's the relevant MsBuild code:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">
        %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
      </PowerShellExe>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
      <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command get-childitem" />
    </Target>
```

All it should do is give a directory listing.  Calling this from cmd.exe works fine:

```
C:\Users\smithj>%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noninteractive -executionpolicy unrestricted -command dir
```

Trying this:

```
msbuild Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release
```

Gets me this:

```
AfterBuild:
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\\tf.exe" che
  ckout Package.nuspec
  Package.nuspec

        %WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
       -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command dir

  Windows PowerShell
  Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

After that, it just hangs forever.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Not sure you're going to like the answer.
After a bit of play, it seems to be about the expansion of the property group. You put a new line in the value of PowerShellExe. 
This works fine:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PowerShellExe Condition=" '$(PowerShellExe)'=='' ">$(WINDIR)\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe</PowerShellExe>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Exec Command="$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy bypass -command &quot;&amp;{get-childitem}&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Well I certainly didn't see that coming.  You're absolutely right.  Incidentally it doesn't like newlines in the command property either.  Anyway, you hit the nail on the head.  I spent hours on this.. It's always something stupid in the end :)  Thank you VERY much!

Comment: I fought with this for hours.  I wish there was a better answer than just "don't put line breaks in the msbuild file."  I wonder if an extra semicolon or something would ultimately get around this?  Basically, I think it is waiting on the terminating line to be entered just like in powershell when you span multiple lines with line breaks you have to put an extra one at the end.  Either way, what a relief that I can at least work around this.  I hate spinning my wheels on this kind of stuff.

Comment: Have you tried ^ this can used as a line breaker in msbuild Exec commands

Comment: Wow...crazy that was the issue. As soon as I removed the newline from the command it worked beautifully. Thanks for posting this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Exec Command='$(PowerShellExe) -NonInteractive -executionpolicy Unrestricted -command "& {Get-ChildItem}"' />
```

Comment: No dice.  An exact copy/paste yields a syntax error, but even after escaping the "&" with "&amp;" it's still just hanging :(